# Error easy-captcha npm installing in sailsJS

Tags: node.js, npm, sails.js, captcha

I have run on terminal to install easy-captcha for my app.

```
npm install easy-captcha --save
```

and error appeared:

```
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/home/haihv94/Applications/nodejs/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:269:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.19.0-25-generic
gyp ERR! command "node" "/home/haihv94/Applications/nodejs/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/haihv94/NDM/ndm.org/node_modules/easy-captcha
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.7
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Linux 3.19.0-25-generic
npm ERR! argv "/home/haihv94/Applications/nodejs/bin/node" "/home/haihv94/Applications/nodejs/bin/npm" "install" "easy-captcha" "--save"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! easy-captcha@0.1.5 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the easy-captcha@0.1.5 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the easy-captcha package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls easy-captcha
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/haihv94/NDM/ndm.org/npm-debug.log
```

I've tried installing another npm to using captcha (s.a recaptcha, node-captcha) but same error! 
How can I solve this problem? thanks all!

Comment: easy-captcha is not working with node v0.12. see [issue](https://github.com/ellman/easy-captcha/issues/2). You need to find something more actual.

Comment: i've used npm captchappng instead easy-captcha, my problem'as solved! thanks bros :)

Comment: [recaptacha2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/recaptcha2) works very well